# How to compare cells values from two different csv using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have two csv files, they have the same columns (filename and MD5), however, the values are in different rows (filename in csv1 is in row 2 (row 1 is header) however, the same filename in csv2 maybe in row 5.

I've tried the "merge" module with the "how" set to: right, left, inner, an outer; the results added additional rows and columns were added.  I also tried the "isin" module.

```
matchfiles = (df1.Filename.isin(df2.Filename)
```

and

```
if (df1[['Filename','MD5']]) == (df2[['Filename','MD5']]):
    print(df1[['Filename','MD5']])
```

I expect the output to print the "Filename" with the matching "MD5".

The errors are:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'bool'
```

and

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

**DataSet 1:**
Filename            MD5

I417122 - KP -pst   125e46b4477934fa7495f
I417122 - KP - xml  eee4acefced33e6595a32
J944737 - DJ gif    f52483135c9e8f6fb2680
J944737 - DJ txt    c1b76990e2e19a7eb2332
J944737 - DJ doc    b1aa2e981d8c04860810
J944737 - DJ docx   55b325a7ef73ba8a0e2f9
J944737 - JD.zip    47fcccba65018d88a3c7e

**DataSet 2:**
Filename            MD5

I417122 - KP -pst   125e46b4477934fa7495f
I417122 - KP - xml  47fcccba65018d88a3c7e
J944737 - DJ gif    f52483135c9e8f6fb2680
J944737 - DJ txt    c1b76990e2e19a7eb2856
J944737 - DJ doc    eee4acefced33e6595a32
J944737 - DJ docx   55b325a7ef73ba8a0e2f9
J944737 - JD.zip    47fcccba65018d88a3c7e

**Expected Results:**
Filename            MD5

I417122 - KP -pst   125e46b4477934fa7495f
J944737 - DJ gif    f52483135c9e8f6fb2680
J944737 - DJ doc    eee4acefced33e6595a32
J944737 - DJ docx   55b325a7ef73ba8a0e2f9
J944737 - JD.zip    47fcccba65018d88a3c7e

Comment: Please edit, and add tables of how your datasets look like. This would help answering your question tremendously. Also add the desired output

Comment: you definitely need to format your question..nobody is going to understand what you are asking for.

Comment: You should be able to do something similar to this `pd.merge(df1,df2,on='Filename')` or `pd.merge(df1[["md5","Filename"]],df2[["md5","Filename"]],on='Filename')`.

Comment: My apologies, new to forum.

Answer (score 0):

This will return a two-column dataframe that has `1` if the filename from csv1 is in csv2 and `0` otherwise.

`matching_df = df1.assign(Indf2=df1.Filename.isin(df2.Filename).astype(int))`

Then you could remove all the rows where the second column is zero and then merge based on `Filename`:

```
matching_df = matching_df[matching_df.Indf2 == 1]
final_df = matching_df.merge(df1, how="left", on="Filename")
final_df = final_df.drop(columns=["Filename_y", "Indf2"])
print(final_df)
```